# Mocking super class method in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-mock

I am implementing the following class:

```
class TestInitializeConnection(TestMyDriver)
```

The super class (TestMyDriver) is a TestCase, meaning:

```
class TestMyDriver(test.TestCase):
```

the **super class** has an attribute named driver that basically is sort of a mock of the tested driver and it declared as follows:

```
self.driver = mocks.MyDriver()
```

now In my (TestInitializeConnection) I want to implement the following test:

```
def test_initialize_connection(self):
    self.driver.initialize_connection(self.volume, self.connector)
```

Somewhere in the code of the function **initialize_connection**, there is a private method that is being called

```
specs = self._get_specs(volume)
```

and I want to make my test to tell this call of **_get_specs(volume)** to return a specific value, for example a dictionary with the value:
{'iops': 100, 'bandwith': 200}

What is the best way of doing so?

Thanks,
Matan

Comment: You can follow @Dan's suggestion but... my rule is avoid to mock private method. What `_get_spec()` do? Is there a way to obtain the same result by mocking some collaborators? Is it possible to make a safe refactoring to help these kind of tests? More use to mock private methods and attributes and more your code become tangled to tests -> refactoring become very hard and you are loosing the ability to change your code that is the best advantage that tests give to you.

Answer (score 0):

Just mock it out.

```
def test_initialize_connection(self):
  with mock.patch.object(
      self.driver, 
      '_get_specs', 
      return_value='your_fake_value') as mock_specs:
    # Do something with self.driver
```

Comment: Thanks Dan,Is there anyway to use the @patch annotation in order to avoid the with?

Comment: Just use `self.driver._get_specs = mock.MagicMock()` followed by `self.driver._get_specs.return_value = 'fake_value'`